# Final bits on my Game Of Life program. Seemingly random results

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

So I *think* I'm nearly done on my game of life program, yet each pass of a grid is not how it should be, even though I feel I've implemented the rules correctly (see golRules). 
Since our assignment has to be submitted with a specific input, the input is as follows:
rows columns steps
[Starting grid]

So an example input would be:
6 6 20 
.X...X 
X.X.X. 
X...X. 
X..XX. 
..XX.X 
...X.X

Yet my the first step of this particular example returns
X..X.X
XX...X
XX....
X..X..
.....X
.....X

If you're familiar with the game of life you'll notice this is totally wrong. I have a feeling in the golRules function when generating the next grid, its updating a specific element one by one, instead of all at the end.
Anyone lend a guy a hand please?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int neighbourCount(int m, int n, char grid[m][n]){
int count = 0;

if(grid[m-1][n-1] == 'X') {
    count++;
}
if(grid[m-1][n] == 'X') {
    count++;
}
if(grid[m-1][n+1] == 'X') {
    count++;
}
if(grid[m][n-1] == 'X') {
    count++;
}
if(grid[m][n+1] == 'X') {
    count++;
}
if(grid[m+1][n-1] == 'X') {
    count++;
}
if(grid[m+1][n] == 'X') {
    count++;
}
if(grid[m+1][n+1] == 'X') {
    count++;
}

return count;
}

void printGrid(int m, int n, char grid[m][n]) {

int i, j;
for(i=0; i<m; i++) {
    for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
        printf("%c", grid[i][j]);
        if(j==m - 1){
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
printf("\n");
}

void golRules(int m, int n, char grid[m][n]) {
int i;
int j;
int neighbour;
for(i=0; i<m; i++) {
    for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
        neighbour = neighbourCount(i, j, grid);
        if(neighbour == 3) {
            grid[i][j] = 'X';
        }else if(neighbour == 2 && grid[i][j] =='X') {
            grid[i][j] = 'X';
        }else {
            grid[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
}
}

int main(){

int row;
int column;
int steps;
scanf("%d %d %d", &row, &column, &steps);

char grid[row][column];

int i, j;
for(i=0; i<row; i++) {
    for(j=0;j<column;j++) {
        scanf(" %c", &grid[i][j]);
    }
}

printGrid(row, column, grid);

for(i=0; i<steps; i++) {
    golRules(row, column, grid);
    printGrid(row, column, grid);
}
}
```

Comment: Your current implementation counts neighbors, then changes the cell--which will affect the neighbor count of cells you haven't gotten to yet. You have to have two grids, or some other method of only changing the grid cells after neighbors are counted for all cells based on the old contents.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Been trying to implement this into my code for a while now but keep running into dead ends. Mainly where I cant update the original grid outside the golRules function for repurposing. Any chance on elaborating a little further please? thanks for the original comment btw

Comment: Like I said, you either need two grids, or store more info than on/off in each grid cell. How you do that is up to you--I can tell you the problem, but I can't teach you to program.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments points out, you will have to calculate the new cell values from the original one for *all* cells. So you will have to implement some kind of "shadow-grid", which, when fully calculated, is copied over the original grid:

```
void golRules(int m, int n, char grid[m][n]) {
  char shadowgrid[m][n]
  int i;
  int j;
  int neighbour;
  for(i=0; i<m; i++) {
    for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
        neighbour = neighbourCount(i, j, grid);
        if(neighbour == 3) {
            shadowgrid[i][j] = 'X';
        } else if(neighbour == 2 && grid[i][j] =='X') {
            shadowgrid[i][j] = 'X';
        } else {
            shadowgrid[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
  }
  memcpy(grid, shadowgrid, sizeof(shadowgrid));
}
```

This should work as you expect.

Comment: Or better swap the active grid instead of copying everytime.

Comment: @Fredrik Yes, that's another possibility, but I wanted to fix it "minimally-intrusive" ;) (i.e. without changing the interface of the existing functions)

Comment: Fair enough. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. This helped a lot, however I think my problem lies in the neighbourCount Function now, where the values around the border are somehow registering an incorrect number of neighbours. I tested this with printf for various values, for example, the top left character registered 3 neighbours with the example input, yet this clearly isnt right. Just wondering how to implement a way to make sure the borders are registering the right amount of neighbours.